# Is there a way to set the number of rows to run on the TestContext from the number of rows that was returned

Tags: selenium, mstest

I know we can use `DataSource` attribute to decorate a `TestMethod` and do data driven testing. Is it possible to set number of rows to run after the data has returned? For example, if I get back 100 rows, is there a way to specify that I only want to run 25 rows instead of 100 rows?

```
[DataSource(connectionstring, "tableName")]
[TestMethod]
public void DoSomething()
{
    // Do something here
}
```

I was also thinking of doing a for loop within the `TestMethod` and 
calling the data source to get the number of rows that I want from the data source. But the problem is I would still have is to be able to set `TestContext`, and if the test fails inside of the for loop, then it seems like it would be more of a headache to fix.

I haven't fleshed this idea out but those were some of the alternatives that I've considered.

Comment: Imho you cannot do it with `DataSourceAttribute`, but you can always use `DynamicDataAttribute`. Take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/RFCs/006-DynamicData-Attribute.md You can write you own method to query database and limit your results accordingly.

Comment: Possibly more importantly, _why_ are you taking this approach?

Comment: @natn2323 I just want to be able to set and control how many test i run, even though its set to run whatever number of rows that is returned from the data source, this is pretty rigid.  How about if i'm testing something out and just want to run it 1 time instead of 100 times.

Comment: Thanks @Peska for the information